# Test on Ordinal data with interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a query regarding statistical analysis. I have collected data on percentage of savings done by individuals. 
These data are ordinal, grouped into equal intervals with the exception of the final category representing all savings of 50% or higher. Because of this, I gather I can't apply a parametric test.

I want to study whether there is significant difference in saving habits of two groups. Please suggest an appropriate test. I have a screen shot of the data.

Would a t-test or Mann Whitney U-test be appropriate?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the intervals are equally spaced, the data are perhaps ordinal by name only. The T-test summarizes the actual mean difference in % savings. Alas, the largest threshold group is not equal in spacing to the prior groups. So you must reframe the question slightly.

If a non-parametric test is a consideration, then perhaps you are less interested in quantifying the actual % difference between men and women. In that case, you could use the T-test anyway and comment on the statistical significance as suggesting whether one group saves *more* or *less* than the other. This "non-parametric T test" is asymptotically equivalent to the Mann-Whitney test.

Another approach is to use ordinal logistic regression. This is also called a proportional odds model. Expand the data using a full data matrix of 252+98 observations or use a weighted dataset for the 10 tabular values:

```
Sex     Savings Weight
Male    0       100
Male    1       102
Male    2       ...
Male    3
Male    4
Female  0
Female  1
Female  2
Female  3
Female  4
```

Then fit the model with Savings as a response, sex as the main predictor, and supply the Weight to obtain a semi-parametric test of statistical significance.

Lastly, you are not forbidden from using a parametric model. Simply declare an underlying parametric model for the distribution of savings, and use expectation-maximization to estimate the latent beta (or other appropriate) distribution of savings in males and in females, then estimate the T-test of association.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the response by @AdamO, in my experience with this kind of data, a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test usually corresponds to ordinal regression pretty well.

I have some plots on this question [near the bottom of this webpage](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/E_01.html).

As always, it's best not to put too much emphasis on the *p*-value, but to also assess the size of the effect. Looking at the proportions in each category for each sex, it's clear that Male has a higher proportion in "below 10%" than does Female, and that Female has higher proportions in some of the higher categories.  But the overall size of the differences is relatively small: Vargha and Delaney's *A* suggests that the probability of Female having a higher observation than Male is only 0.57 (95% confidence interval, 0.502, 0.629, not shown below).  Whether this effect size has practical importance is up to you.

For this data in R:

```
Data = read.table(header=T, text="
Sex     Response  Weight
Male    1         100
Male    2         102
Male    3          35
Male    4           8
Male    5           6
Male    6           1
Female  1          30
Female  2          40
Female  3          16
Female  4           7
Female  5           3
Female  6           2
")

Long = Data[rep(row.names(Data), Data$Weight), c("Sex", "Response")]

rownames(Long) = seq(1:nrow(Long))


wilcox.test(Response ~ Sex, data = Long)

   ### Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
   ### 
   ### W = 13986, p-value = 0.03986


library(ordinal)

Long$Response.f = factor(Long$Response, ordered = TRUE)

model = clm(Response.f ~ Sex, data = Long)

library(emmeans)

joint_tests(model)

   ### model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
   ### Sex          1 Inf   4.284  0.0385

library(effsize)

VD.A(Response ~ Sex, data = Long)

   ### Vargha and Delaney A
   ###
   ### A estimate: 0.5663265 (negligible)

library(lattice)

histogram(~ Response.f | Sex, data=Long, layout=c(1,2), col ="darkgray")

prop.table(xtabs(~ Response.f + Sex, data=Long), margin=2)
   ###           Sex
   ###  Response.f      Female        Male
   ###           1 0.306122449 0.396825397
   ###           2 0.408163265 0.404761905
   ###           3 0.163265306 0.138888889
   ###           4 0.071428571 0.031746032
   ###           5 0.030612245 0.023809524
   ###           6 0.020408163 0.003968254
```

[image]